# subdomain-fu gem tld_size

Tags: ruby-on-rails, subdomain-fu

What does it mean the **tld_size** in the subdomain-fu gem. for example deafult am having,

```
  SubdomainFu.tld_sizes = {:development => 1,
   :test => 0,
   :production => 1}
```

in my initializers/subdomain-fu.rb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have debugged and found the answer,

If the config as follows means,

```
 SubdomainFu.tld_sizes = {:development => 1,
  :test => 0,
  :production => 1}
```

If your URL is test.lvh.me:3000 means the subdomain-fu gem's current_subdomain will return test.
If you set the tld_size is as below,

```
 SubdomainFu.tld_sizes = {:development => 1,
  :test => 0,
  :production => 0}
```

Then your URL is test.lvh.me:3000 means the subdomain-fu gem's current_subdomain will return test.lvh

Thanks...